# Many actions when there is a click / save state of variable when change of html page

Tags: javascript, html

I want to do 2 actions when I click on a picture on a HTML page.
These 2 actions are:

- change a trigger (it's a specific action, and it works when I click)
- change a picture.

This is **a part** of my HTML code :

```
<div class="col c1-11">
      <p><a onclick="return toggle(this);" data-on="/trigger/2" data-off="/trigger/3" href="/trigger/3"><img src="images/mur1/V_1_OFF.png" /></a></p>
</div>

<div class="col c1-11">
      <p><a onclick="return toggle1(this)" data-on="/trigger/4" data-off="/trigger/5" href="/trigger/5"><img src="images/mur1/V_2_OFF.png"></a></p>
</div>
```

This is **a part** of my javascript code :

```
function toggle(element)
{
  var onLink = element.getAttribute('data-on');
  var offLink = element.getAttribute('data-off');

  if (element.getAttribute("href") == offLink){
    element.setAttribute("href", onLink);  //It works
    element.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src = "images/mur1/V_1_ON.png";
  } else if (element.getAttribute("href") == onLink){
    element.setAttribute("href", offLink);  //It works
    element.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src = "images/mur1/V_1_OFF.png";
  }
    return false;
}

function toggle1(element)
{
  var onLink = element.getAttribute('data-on');
  var offLink = element.getAttribute('data-off');

  if (element.getAttribute("href") == offLink){
    element.setAttribute("href", onLink);  //It works
    element.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src = "images/mur1/V_2_ON.png";
  } else if (element.getAttribute("href") == onLink){
    element.setAttribute("href", offLink);  //It works
    element.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src = "images/mur1/V_2_OFF.png";
  }
    return false;
}
```

Considering I have many pictures, do I need one function for each picture?

Other question, for example, I click once on my picture1 ; the picture on my screen is `"images/mur1/V_1_ON.png"`, no problem.

But if I left my page and I come again on this page, it reload and as default, the picture is `<img src="images/mur1/V_1_OFF.png" />`, like in my html code. How can I keep `"images/mur1/V_1_ON.png"` on the screen?
Clearly, I must save the state of my `<img>` even if I change of html page.
Do you know how can I do?

Comment: You want to use `element.querySelector('img').setAttribute('src', ...);`.

Comment: There is no attribute called `img src`

Comment: You need to first get the `img` element and set its `src` attribute to new image path..

Comment: The `element` you are referring to is the `< href>`. Your image is a child of that element.

Comment: @Phylogenesis , your function doesn't work.

Comment: @PeeHaa , I chnage my attribute and I call it only `src`, it doesn't work either.

Comment: @Kaf, get and after set, I understand. But what is the function to do that (I sorry, I started in html and js )

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are not selecting the img. You are effectively trying to change an attribute of `img` on the a element.

You'll want something like this, although I haven't tested it:

```
element.getElementsByTagName('img').setAttribute("src", "images/mur1/V_1_ON.png");
```

**Update**

First off your `img` had no closing tags. Secondly your click events didn't return anything, aka you weren't stopping the default behavior of your `href`'s

You'll need to change your html to this:

```
<div class="col c1-11">
    <p><a id="btn1" onclick="return toggle(this);" data-on="/trigger/2" data-off="/trigger/3" href="/trigger/3"><img src="images/mur1/V_1_OFF.png" /></a></p>
    </div>
<div class="col c1-11">
    <p><a id="btn1" onclick="return toggle(this);" data-on="/trigger/4" data-off="/trigger/5" href="/trigger/5"><img src="images/mur1/V_2_OFF.png" /></a></p>
    </div>
```

Your js to this:

```
function toggle(element)
{
  var onLink = element.getAttribute('data-on');
  var offLink = element.getAttribute('data-off');

  if (element.getAttribute("href") == offLink){
    element.setAttribute("href", onLink);  //It works
    element.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src = "images/mur1/V_1_OFF.png";
  } else if (element.getAttribute("href") == onLink){
    element.setAttribute("href", offLink);  //It works
    element.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src = "images/mur1/V_1_ON.png";
  }
    return false;
}
```

I have as suggested by `kaf` that `getElementsByTagName` returns an array so using `[0]` selects the first returned element. In this case the img, if you added any new elements to that you'd need to update the `[0]` or write a better function to detect the `img`'s in that.

I've returned false and made the `href` return the function to the click event. So it will not follow to the original `href`'s target. Remove the `return false;` line if you would like it to follow the url in the `href`

Here is a fiddle of the project working:
https://jsfiddle.net/ogzpozxt/

Comment: Why couldn't I change my picture in my html code, like the trigger?Isn't it possible?

Comment: You could change it, thats what you want to do but you're doing `element.setAttribute("img src",` which is trying to set an attribute of `img` but of course `img` is an element not an attribute. Can you paste the output of `console.info(element.getElementsByTagName('img'))` put that inside the function `toggle`

Comment: You need to use `element.getElementsByTagName('img')[0]`. It returns a collection of elements, not just a single one.

Comment: I must write this?  `function toggle(element)
{
  var onLink = element.getAttribute('data-on');  
  var offLink = element.getAttribute('data-off');  
  console.info(element.getElementsByTagName('img'))  
  if (element.getAttribute("href") == offLink){  
    element.setAttribute("href", onLink);  
    element.getElementsByTagName('img').setAttribute("src", "images/mur1/V_1_OFF.png");  
  } else if (element.getAttribute("href") == onLink){  
    element.setAttribute("href", offLink);  
    element.getElementsByTagName('img').setAttribute("src", "images/mur1/V_1_ON.png");  
  }
}`

Comment: Please see updated answer and tell me how you get on with that.

Comment: @JamieHutber, Firstly, your code works ; but I have 2 questions : I have many pictures on my pages, do I have created as many functions as picture? All my pictures go by 2 (exemple `V_1_ON.png` and `V_1_OFF.png` for the picture 1 ) ; but I have many picture on a page, so how can I do?

Comment: @JamieHutber, can you have a look at my updated question?

Comment: Nope, the function is already working out the box on individual photos. Just give each `a` the function `toggle` and it will change the image for you. Don't forget to accept this answer as correct :)

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't understand your answer.

Comment: It should work on each link. There is no need to create more functions.

Comment: But the name of the picture change everytime. For the picture one, there are `V_1_ON.png` and `V_1_OFF.png`. For the picture two, there are `V_2_ON_.ng` and `V_2_OFF.png`, ect...  Imagine, in my case I have about 50 pictures, and my function toogle only use `V_1_ON_png` and `V_1_OFF_png`. That's why I say that.

Comment: argh i didn't realise this. I'll update the answer for you :) I'll be able to do it later maybe tomoroow if i can't find time

Comment: @JamieHutber, Hi, do you find the answer?;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this (note: you have two elements with same id (`btn1`) in your html):

```
element.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src = "images/mur1/V_1_OFF.png";
```

Your code would be like

```
function toggle(element)
{
  var onLink = element.getAttribute('data-on');
  var offLink = element.getAttribute('data-off');

  if (element.getAttribute("href") == offLink){

    element.setAttribute("href", onLink);  //It works

    //Get the image into a variable and then set src attribute
    var img = element.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
    img.src = "images/mur1/V_1_OFF.png"; 

  } else if (element.getAttribute("href") == onLink){

    element.setAttribute("href", offLink);  //It works

    //Same as above in a single line
    element.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src = "images/mur1/V_1_ON.png";

  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, is it a problem as I'm not using this element?

Comment: your comment isn't clear. Basically, `src` is an attribute of `image`. `element.getElementsByTagName('img')[0]` is giving you the 0th `img` element within the anchor.

Comment: Excuse I'm French, I don't understand everything. I just don't know what can I write in my code instead off  `my id="btn1"` because I don't use this in my html code and in my js code.

Comment: Replace the lines commented as "//doesn't work" with my answer.

Comment: Have a look my updated answer. I've done a breakdown version for you to understand getting the element first and using it afterwords.

Comment: first question, can I delete my id `btn1` in my code?What is their role in my application? And second things, i try your code but the picture stay the same when I click.

Comment: Element ids has to be unique. Change second button id to something like `id="btn2"` and the other thing is you need to make sure there are such images in the given location..

Comment: Couldn't I just delete `id="btn1"` on all my lines?I don't serve of it!

Comment: Well if you don't use it anywhere else in your code, you can delete it.